# SAS Macro variable not resolving inside of PROC SQL SELECT INTO : Statement

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in which i have to remove all of the columns with a certain ending. I am trying to do this dynamically as the dataset will updated each year and the columns that need to be dropped will have a different ending each year, and I would like all of the things that need to be changed to be at the beginning of the program for max transferability.

I have a proc sql statement that works properly when I use the actual value but doesn't work when I replace the value with a macro variable call. Any help as to why this is happening and how i can fix it would be much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
/* update these values on an annual basis */ 
/* YO = year observed */ 
%let YO = 19; 
/*YOminus1 = year observed minus 1
           , the year before the observed year */
%let YOminus1 = 18; 

data mydata;
        var_2016 = 'test';
        var_2017 = 100;
        var_2018 = 'test2';
        var_2019 = 120;
run;
    
proc contents data=mydata out=contents(keep=name) noprint; run;
proc sql noprint;
 select name into :droplist separated by ' ' from contents
    where upcase(name) like '%&YOminus1'
       or upcase(name) like '%&YO'
 ; 
quit;   
data mydata2;
  set mydata (drop=&droplist); 
run;
```

Comment: Macro code is not evaluated when inside of strings bounded by single quote characters.  Use double quote characters instead.  `"%&YOminus1"`

Answer (score 0):

As @Tom states in OP comment, use double quotes (`"`) so that the macro processor can resolve the macro variable in the where clause.

```
where upcase(name) like "%&YOminus1"
   or upcase(name) like "%&YO"
```

However, the WHERE clause is using SQL wildcard `%` to indicate the desired value must end in the resolved value. If the value *suffix* to test for was **not** a numeric, the macro system would issue either

- `WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro suffix not resolved.`
- or, actually invoke `%suffix`

Note: `%&` *might* lead to odd or subtle unexpected resolutions.

The safest solution would be to use `%nrstr(%%)` inside the double quotes in order to mask `%` and render the `%` as plain character when SAS supervisor hands off the submit code stream to the SQL parser.

```
where upcase(name) like "%nrstr(%%)&YOminus1"
   or upcase(name) like "%nrstr(%%)&YO"
```

What happens if plain `%` or `%str(%%)` is used in an attempt to express the  `%` as a SQL where wildcard character?  This following sample code shows that the desired 1 row result is not achieved.  Only `%nrstr(%%)` inside the  double quotes gets the expected 1 row result.

```
data have;
  input name $;
datalines;
x123
xy22
aa12
aa21
aa34
;

%let yo=22;

options symbolgen;

%macro x_pct;

proc sql;
  create table want_str as select * from have
  where 
    name like "%&yo"
  ;
quit;

%mend;

%macro x_str;

proc sql;
  create table want_str as select * from have
  where 
    name like "%str(%%)&yo"
  ;
quit;

%mend;

%macro x_nrstr;

proc sql;
  create table want_nrstr as
  select * from have
  where 
    name like "%nrstr(%%)&yo"
  ;
quit;

%mend;

options mprint;

%x_pct
%x_str
%x_nrstr
```

Log

[image]

Comment: Why %NRSTR() instead of just %STR()?  Why would just want to delay the macro processor from evaluating that % character instead of preventing it from evaluating it?

Comment: The `%` desired use is to be used as a SQL context wildcard.  I've added more examples to post

Comment: So using %STR(%%) seems to trigger some strange interaction causing the macro value to appear twice and also the & to be included in the generated string.  `There were 0 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.   WHERE name like '%&2222';`  You can use %QUOTE(%) instead.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I rarely interact with `%QUOTE`, not sure why :)